# A problem on probability involving binomial distribution

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the method required to solve this problem, so I stripped out the actual values to keep from getting a direct answer.

> A random sample of $n$ people who walk to work are chosen, what is the probability that **at least** $r$ of them are injured, given that the probability of being injured while walking to work is $p$.

I don't know where to go.  It feels like a binomial probability problem, but it covers a range of trials and not just one value exactly.  My guess was to calculate `1-BinomCDF(n, p, r - 1)`.  Does this seem accurate?  For example, if $n = 15$, $r = 7$, $p = 0.5$.

I would have `1-BinomCDF(15, 0.5, 6)`
or $$1-\sum_{i=1}^6 {15\choose i}0.5^i(1-0.5)^{15-i}.$$

Answer (score 3):

You are right, this does use the binomial distribution.$$Pr(X=r)={n\choose r}p^r(1-p)^{n-r}$$
That simply gives the probability that "r" events are true from a total of "n" possible events, with the probability of the event happening being "p"

So using your values:$$\sum_{i=7}^n Pr(X=i)$$
$$=\sum_{i=7}^n{15\choose i}0.5^i(1-0.5)^{15-i}$$

Comment: $Pr(X=7)={15\choose 7}0.5^7(1-0.5)^{15-7}$ just gives the probability for the amount injured = 7, but not the range of 7 to n, correct?

Comment: My bad, you are correct. So what you need to do is add up the all the probabilities above and including r=7

Comment: $1-\sum_{i=1}^6 {15\choose i}0.5^i(1-0.5)^{15-i}$?

Comment: The problem is looking for the range from n to c, not 1 to r.

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: $1-\sum_{i=1}^6 {15\choose i}0.5^i(1-0.5)^{15-i}$ and $=\sum_{i=7}^n{15\choose i}0.5^i(1-0.5)^{15-i}$ are the same thing

Comment: Gotcha, I must've misread your comment.  Thanks for the help.  Glad this solidified it for me.